# Alternative to write SOQL out of FOR in Batch Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, governorlimits

I have following trigger executing after record is inserted and calls a batch to process records. In this batch I have few IF conditions to update records. Due to business scenario I have to write SOQL in FOR loop but it is throwing limit exceeded 201 exception which is pretty hitting governor Limit. Any alternative to put this SOQL out of FOR loop?

Trigger:

```
List<CustomLog> logList = new List<CustomLog>();
trigger CreateLog on CustomLog ( After Insert ) {
for ( CustomLog log :  Trigger.New ) {
            logList.add(emailEventLog);
    }
}
Database.executeBatch(new CreateLogBatch(logList));
```

Batch:

```
List<CustomLog> newLogs = new List<CustomLog>();
List<CustomLog> updateLogs = new List<CustomLog>();

global CreateLogBatch(List<CustomLog> logsFromTrigger) {
    newLogs = logsFromTrigger;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext BC ) {
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM CustomLog WHERE Id IN : newLogs]);
}

global void execute( Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CustomLog> returnedLogs ) {
    List<FilterLog> FilLog = new List<FilterLog>();
    for ( CustomLog extractLog : returnedLogs ) {
        CustomLog log = [SELECT Id FROM CustomLog WHERE Id =: extractLog.Id];
        //I am getting FilLog No as input and fetching ID based on it to populate lookup values.
        // Here it is throwing limit exception.
        if( String.isNotBlank( extractLog.LogIDNO ) )
            FilLog = [SELECT Id FROM FilterLog WHERE FilLogIdNo = : extractLog.LogIDNO ];
        log.FilLogId = FilLog.Id
        updateLogs.add(log);
    }
    Update updateLogs
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yeah very bad practice. If you cannot figure out how to move your query out of the loop, you need to push yourself harder.

Consider for example this code

```
CustomLog log = [SELECT Id FROM CustomLog WHERE Id =: extractLog.Id];
```

The above code accomplishes exactly one thing. It consumes your governor limits. That's all it does. It doesn't even give you **ANY NEW INFORMATION**. Change the loop variable name to log, remove this query, and you will see a vast improvement in consumption rates.

Here's how you would do the collection based approach

```
Set<String> logNumbers = new Set<String>();
for (CustomLog log : logs)
{
    logNumbers.add(log.LogIDNO);
}
Map<String, FilterLog> filterLogMap = new Map<String, FilterLog>();
for (FilterLog log : [SELECT FilLogIdNo FROM FilterLog WHERE FilLogIdNo IN :logNumbers])
{
    filterLogMap.put(log.FilLogIdNo, log);
}
```

Now when you loop through your `CustomLog` records for logic, you can retrieve them by this key.

```
Set<String> logNumbers = new Set<String>();
for (CustomLog customLog : customLogs)
{
    FilterLog correspondingFilterLog = filterLogMap.get(customLog.LogIDNO);
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make repeated queries against `FilterLog`. You can collect all the required `FilLogIdNo` values, query the whole lot, then build a map from the `FilLogIdNo` to the `FilterLog` ID. Something like this will probably work:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<CustomLog> returnedLogs)
{
    /* Determine which filter logs we're going to need. */
    Set<Id> filLogIdNos = (new Map<Id,SObject>(returnedLogs)).keySet();

    /* Retrieve all required filter logs. */
    List<FilterLog> filterLogs = [
        SELECT Id, FilLogIdNo
        FROM FilterLog
        WHERE FilLogIdNo IN :filLogIdNos];

    /* We want to be able to look up a specific FilterLog record ID based on
     * its filLogIdNo. */
    Map<Id, Id> filLogIdNoToId = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for (FilterLog log : filterLogs)
        filLogIdNoToId.put(log.FilLogIdNo, log.Id);

    for (CustomLog referenceLog : returnedLogs)
    {
        /* From our lookup map, retrieve the appropriate FilterLog ID. */
        Id filterLogId = filLogIdNoToId.get(extractLog.LogIDNO);
        /* If the log doesn't have an associated filter log, we skip it. */
        if (filterLogId == null)
            continue;

        /* We can save ourself a query by instantiating the CustomLog with
         * an ID instead of SELECTing it. */
        updateLogs.add(new CustomLog(
            Id = extractLog.Id,
            FilLogId = filterLogId);
    }

    update updateLogs;
}
```

I am also not sure why `updateLogs` needs to be an instance variable instead of local to the method `execute` method, but that's your call.

Also, for the sake of those answering your questions, please indent your code consistently before posting. Reading code I didn't write is already difficult enough; no need to make my job harder!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered querying the entire possible set of data you'll need into a list, then iterate over the list to process the results?  You can load the records into a separate list variable within the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have two SOQL calls inside for loops.  This is very bad practice in Salesforce.

The first SOQL is completely unneccessary as you are querying the exact same records you already have.

For the second one try collecting all the LogIDNO's in a set, and query them all at once.  Then loop through those and populate your extractLog.

Comment: I agree its bad practice but If I don't write first SOQL then I am getting CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY exception. I can try second scenario.

Comment: @JavaAster - So you are doing this in an after update? Either do it in a before update or simply query the records once at the beginning.

Comment: @Eric OP says it's a batch. I haven't seen that exception outside of triggers either, though, for the most part.